# Need a progress bar for $http method in angularjs 1.6.5

Tags: angularjs, progress-bar

what I am trying to do is add a progress bar to my template that will dynamically keep on updating its value according to the progress of my file upload. I have used angular-loading-bar but I want to have my own for the following $http request:-

```
        $http.patch(url, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        }).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
        function successCallback(response){
            console.log("Success");
            console.log(response);
        };
        function errorCallback(error){
            alert("Error Uploading!");
            console.log(error);
        };
```

And I want to update my following progressbar:-

```
<div class="progress">
     <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{ progress }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{ progress }} %">
        {{ progress }} %
     </div>
</div>
```

Where the `{{ progress }}` should be my file upload percentage value. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add uploadEventHandlers as shown below:-

```
        $http.patch(url, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
            uploadEventHandlers: {
                progress: function (e) {
                          if (e.lengthComputable) {
                             $scope.progressBar = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                             console.log($scope.progressBar)
                          }
                }
            }
        }).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
        function successCallback(response){
            console.log("Success");
            console.log(response);
        };
        function errorCallback(error){
            alert("Error Uploading!");
            console.log(error);
        };
```

And Then  in html:-

```
<div class="progress">
     <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{progressBar}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{progressBar}}%">
                                                {{progressBar}}
     </div>
 </div>
```